# Display huge data in charts

Tags: php, javascript, charts

I have to design charts for a big amout of datas ... I have more than 6000 points to show.
Each point have a X-Y position, and a specific color.

I achieved this using JpGraph and editing it's Core, but, it's slow... Very slow. 
I can't get more than 4K points.

Someone already deal with this kind of charts ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is going to sound negative, it's not meant to so I apologise in advance.

This is an almost impossible task without aggregating your data. Let me explain why.

Firstly have you considered how large the points will be? To do this with any accuracy would require points that were in the region of single pixel sized points. Honestly you will not be able to get a chart to show meaningful colors if each point was the size of one pixel.

Secondly the above would be on the assumption that the chart itself filled the entire display and that everyone who was seeing your chart used the same resolution display.If anyone was looking at your chart with a lower resolution display, the data would either be off the screen or the points would be sub-pixel size, and disapear.

If your points are larger than a pixel you have to consider the physical scale of the chart, and if you allow for some parts to be off-the-screen so-to-speak, then logically you only have to render the visible section, thus avoiding your rendering time issue.

I think if a client has given this task to you it hasn't been thought out well enough, and you should go back to them with these points.

If it's your own task, think again as to what it is you want to show, and how you can aggregate the data in a meaningful way.

Comment: Thanks for this analyze. You are right, this is crazy :) But, the goal of these chart is to have a kind of colored surface. The good example is : http://gliderweb.ifm-geomar.de/html/ifm11/depl02/ifm11_depl02_03_0007.png. With JPGraph and Canvas, the result is not so bad. I will continue working on it. Thanks for the answer, I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

tried http://g.raphaeljs.com/ ?
some more:
http://www.instantshift.com/2010/03/09/50-free-resources-for-charts-and-graphs-solution/#frfcags-09

also great for this purpose for you: http://dygraphs.com/